# Different 3D plot in MATLAB and Wolfram Alpha

Tags: matlab, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to plot the function of two variables $f(x,y) = e^{xy}, -2 \leq x \leq 2, -1 \leq y \leq 3$ in MATLAB. Here's the code I'm using:

```
x = [-2:0.1:2]; 
y = [-1:0.1:3];
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = exp(X.*Y);
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

Now, when I run this code I get the following[image]

If I try to plot the same surface with Wolfram Alpha, I get something quite different: [f(x,y) with Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%28xy%29%2C%20-2%20%3C%3D%20x%20%3C%3D%202%2C%20-1%20%3C%3D%20y%20%3C%3D%203)

I tried to update the version of MATLAB (I'm currently using 9.12.0 (R2022a)) but that didn't solve the issue.

Thank you!

Comment: I can believe that the plots are consistent. Your Alpha plot stops at around y=2, so the domains don’t match.

Comment: In the same vein as @bubba 's comment, you have to take symmetrical domains (see my comment following the answer you have received).

Comment: ... otherwise said, trust the Wolfram Alpha result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WolframAlpha plot did two things:  first, it ignored your $y$ range, and instead plotted the function on the square roughly approximating $(x,y) \in [-1.75, 1.75]^2$.  I have no idea why it would select this region to plot; you can see in both the contour plot and the 3D plot, the axis doesn't go all the way to $\pm 2$.  Second, it truncated the vertical axis to plot only the range $f(x,y) \in [0,5.5]$.  The reason for this is at least a bit more clear:  WolframAlpha uses an algorithm to pick the plot range that shows the most "interesting" features of the plot.  If you select the full plot range, the curvature of the region close to the origin is not as immediately obvious.

Here are some plots in *Mathematica* to compare, and the syntax used to generate them:

This command tries to reproduce the Wolfram Alpha plot as faithfully as possible.

```
Plot3D[Exp[x y], {x, -1.75, 1.75}, {y, -1.75, 1.75}, PlotRange -> {0, 5.5}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

This command plots on the square $[-2,2]^2$, showing that the region that Wolfram Alpha chose doesn't correspond to any of the specified plot limits in the original input:

```
Plot3D[Exp[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5.5}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

This command plots the actual input as specified in the Wolfram Alpha query, but keeps the limited vertical axis range:

```
Plot3D[Exp[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 5.5}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Finally, this command forces the full range to be plotted, and corresponds to the Matlab output:

```
Plot3D[Exp[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't think the problem was caused by the selected region to plot. I will pay more attention to that... I use both WolframAlpha and MATLAB for inspecting functions sometimes but I couldn't figure why they would have different behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

Your plot is spot on.

Here is the plot using google (just type plot e^(x*y) in the search bar and change ranges).

[image]

Here is the plot using Mathematica (Plot3D[E^(x y), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> All,
PlotTheme -> "Detailed"])

[image]

To be clear and respond to the objection in comments, here is the plot which is closer representation to what Wolfram provided.

[image]

Comment: I don't agree with your answer. If you don't take a symmetrical square domain $[-a,a] \times [-a,a]$, you miss the main properties of the surface which is its symmetry with respect to planes $y=x$ and $y=-x$ which is well rendered by the Wolfram Alpha plot obtained by agin00 !

Comment: @JeanMarie: However true, that was not the range given for the problem. The problem was why did the Matlab plot not look like the WA plot. However, I still addressed your comment.

Comment: Thank you for the information, both of you! It's more clear now what caused the issue.